# All minimal Levenshtein Distance solutions in C

Tags: c, recursion, levenshtein-distance

I'm supposed to compute the Levenshtein distance of two strings in C.
I have successfully created the matrix and returned the correct Levenshtein Distance, however, now I also need to print all different possible solutions for the minimal Levenshtein Distance

I am trying to do this recursively but I fail everytime.

[image: Some Levenshtein Matrix as a Test]

Here's the code for what I most recently tried:

```
void printLevenshteinSolutions(int const matrix[], int rows, int cols, int r, int c, char* solution){
    
    if((r==0) && (c==0)){
        printf("Solution found:\t|%s|\n", solution);
        solutionCount++;
    }
    else{
        int currentIndex = convertMatrixIndex(r, c, cols);
        int leftIndex = convertMatrixIndex(r-1, c, cols);
        int topIndex = convertMatrixIndex(r, c-1, cols);
        int diagonalIndex = convertMatrixIndex(r-1, c-1, cols);
        char oldSolution[MAX];
        strcpy(oldSolution, solution);

        if(matrix[currentIndex] >= matrix[leftIndex]){
            if((matrix[leftIndex]<=matrix[topIndex]) && (matrix[leftIndex]<=matrix[diagonalIndex])){
                strcat(solution, "d");
                if((r-1>=0))
                    printLevenshteinSolutions(matrix, rows, cols, r-1, c, solution);
                strcpy(solution, oldSolution);
            }
        }
        if(matrix[currentIndex] >= matrix[topIndex]){
            if((matrix[topIndex]<=matrix[leftIndex]) && (matrix[topIndex]<=matrix[diagonalIndex])){
                strcat(solution, "i");
                if((c-1>=0))
                    printLevenshteinSolutions(matrix, rows, cols, r, c-1, solution);
                strcpy(solution, oldSolution);

            }
        }
        if(matrix[currentIndex] >= matrix[diagonalIndex]){
            if((matrix[diagonalIndex]<=matrix[topIndex]) && (matrix[diagonalIndex]<=matrix[leftIndex])){
                if(matrix[currentIndex] > matrix[diagonalIndex]){
                    strcat(solution, "c");
                }
                else{
                    strcat(solution, " ");
                }
                if((c-1>=0)&&(r-1>=0))
                    printLevenshteinSolutions(matrix, rows, cols, r-1, c-1, solution);
                strcpy(solution, oldSolution);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This will now output the solution the wrong way around, which I can fix, however the bigger problem is the solutions simply not being correct.

UPDATE::
I am trying to compute possible paths from the bottom right to the top left of the matrix.
I don't just want any paths!
Any connection from one cell to another MUST be going left, top or the top left

Furthermore it also must only go to the minimal values of those three neighboring cells.

e.g:

012 
134 
234

Here the bottom 4 has to connect with the 3 on its left for one possible solution.
It also has to connect to the 3 diagonally to the left of it for another possible solution.
It must not include the path from the bottom 4 to the top 4 since 4 > 3

Comment: Please provide a [mre], with several sets of sample input, output and desired output. Explain the difference between current and desired output (with and without reversal). Use hardcoded data instead of requiring input. Then report on the results of your debugging attempts. Can you pinpoint when exactly the variables diverge from what they should be to produce the desired output?

Comment: For people like me and also for the very helpful effect of rubber ducking ( https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ ) please explain in English what the distance means, how the algorithm is supposed to work and how your code implements it.

Comment: I am trying to compute possible paths from the bottom right to the top left of the matrix. 
I don't just want any paths!
Any connection from one cell to another MUST be going left, top or the top left 

Furthermore it also must only go to the minimal values of those three neighboring cells. 

e.g: 
012
134
234

Here the bottom 4 has to connect with the 3 on its left for one possible solution. It also has to connect to the 3 diagonally to the left of it for another possible solution.
It must not include the path from the bottom 4 to the top 4 since 4 > 3

Does this make any sense?

Comment: Please [edit] that into the question.

Comment: Just did. I also just saw how the format was damaged in this comment.